# ffmpage win7 screen record cursor is not normal

Tags: ffmpeg

I hit a problem when recording screen on window 7 using ffmpeg.

Snapshot here:
[image]

So, you guys see the big red point is recorded mouse cursor.
I am using PPT default pencil, so, actually, cursor is a very small point.
But it becomes so big when play.

Command I use:

```
ffmpeg.exe -y -rtbufsize 500M -f gdigrab -framerate 5  -draw_mouse 1 -i desktop -f dshow -i audio=%s -af "highpass=f=200, lowpass=f=3000" -c:v libx264 -r 5 -preset medium -tune zerolatency -crf 35 -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:a libvo_aacenc -ac 2 -b:a 48k  -fs 50M  -movflags +faststart
```

Anyone hit this before?

Thanks.

Wesley

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved by edit gdigrab.c(493) adding this:

```
if (pos.x >= 0 && pos.x <= clip_rect.right - clip_rect.left &&
        pos.y >= 0 && pos.y <= clip_rect.bottom - clip_rect.top) {
    BITMAP bm;
    BOOL bRet = GetObject(info.hbmMask, sizeof(bm), &bm) == sizeof(bm);
    if(bRet) {
        int cx = bm.bmWidth;
        int cy = info.hbmColor ? bm.bmHeight : bm.bmHeight / 2;
        if(!DrawIconEx (gdigrab->dest_hdc, pos.x, pos.y, icon, cx, cy, 0, NULL, DI_NORMAL))
            CURSOR_ERROR("Couldn't draw icon");     
    }else{
        if (!DrawIcon(gdigrab->dest_hdc, pos.x, pos.y, icon))
            CURSOR_ERROR("Couldn't draw icon");
    }
}
```